# How to resolve FATAL ERROR: Could not find /usr/bin/mysql mariadb on Arch/Manjaro Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, archlinux

I am accidentally delete `/usr/bin/mysql` from my directory. It make an error when I run `mysql_secure_installation` and produce following error message.

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not find /usr/bin/mysql

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location
```

I have already tried to uninstall mariadb using `sudo pacman -Rns mariadb` and installing it again, but `/usr/bin/mysql` not generate. Are someone already face same problem before ?

Comment: Could any of [these archlinux forum results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+find+/usr/bin/mysql+archlinux+site:bbs.archlinux.org&client=firefox-b-1-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIwJiat67oAhUlnuAKHXukDN0QrQIoBDAAegQIBRAP&biw=1366&bih=624) help?

Comment: `/usr/bin/mysql` is provided by `mariadb-clients` ..... I.e. `# pacman -S mariadb-clients`